# Injected property of service class is null but not null for another class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-annotations

I am stuck at this, Lets say, In PMTest, testConfig method, 
when injected, geoService has GeoRep property as null but, GeoRep property of PMTest class is not null. Why does this happen?

Here are my classes

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})

public class PMTest {

@Autowired
private GeoRep geoRep;

@Autowired
private GeoService geoService;

@Test
public void testConfig() {
        geoServive.findAll();
        geoRep.findAll();

    }

}



@Service
public class GeoService {

    @Autowired
    private GeoRep geoRep;
    .
    .
    .
}



@Transactional
public interface GeoRep extends JpaRepository<GeoRegion, Long> {

}
```

any help, appreciated.

In short,

```
PMTest
  -
  - - - - - - GeoService
  -               -
  -               -
  -               - - - - - - GeoRep (is null)
  -          
  -
  -
  - - - - - - - GeoRep (is not null)
```

Comment: Do you have it correctly injected when running in non test context?

Comment: @Abrahamyan Samvel Yes, it works as same

Comment: Where are your @Repository tag and JPA configuration is done correctly? Please share that code also.

Comment: we dont need to mark the repository Interface with @Repository tag, it works in PMTest. I would like to emphasize that while GeoRep of Pmtest is not null , GeoRep of GeoService is null in PMTest class.Autowiring doesnt work in service layer

Comment: Are you sure GeoService  is scanned by spring. If not make sure include corresponding package in @ComponentScan.

Comment: @surya yes, I am sure, by the way when I switched to constructor Injection, geoRep is set however , once I get from context geoRep returns null

Comment: oh ok.  if you define all of these in another configuration file and then import the config file here, then it should work. Its the spring how it loads those bean or you can try using @DependsOn atttribute for GeoService component.